# VBA What's the underlying difference between call Sub or Function with or without parentheses

Tags: arrays, vba, call, parentheses, byref

I had an issue with passing an Array to a Sub By Reference, but the Array actually not get modified.
I managed to fix that , but I want to know why.

Here is the example.

```
Private Function fCountArray(ByRef arrayVar As Variant)
    arrayVar(0) = 333
End Function

Sub Test1()
      Dim changedArr As Variant
      Dim notChangedArr As Variant

    ' create 2 quick array
      changedArr = Array(1, 2, 33, 56, 76, 89, 10)
      notChangedArr = Array(1, 2, 33, 56, 76, 89, 10)

    'intest = Array(3, 1, 2)
     fCountArray (notChangedArr)
     Debug.Print notChangedArr(0) 'Print Out 1

     fCountArray changedArr
     Debug.Print changedArr(0) 'Print Out 333
End Sub
```

So what is the underlying different between **fCountArray (notChangedArr)** and **fCountArray changedArr**

Why **fCountArray (notChangedArr)** Not pass by reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question!  I believe the parentheses are causing an *evaluation*, so even though the function is taking the argument `ByRef`, you're not actually passing it the array local to the calling procedure, you're passing essentially a copy of it.

To avoid ambiguity, I tend to make `Sub` all procedures that don't explicitly *return a value*.  And I use `Function` only to return values/evaluate an expression, never to manipulate objects/etc.

So I would do:

```
Sub fCountArray(ByRef arrayVar As Variant)
    arrayVar(0) = 333
End Sub
```

And then you can simply call that sub like:

```
fCountArray notChangedArr
```

(You may not need to make this `Private`, since it takes at least one required argument it will not be exposed to user in the macros dialog.)

I tested this also with `String` and observe the same behavior.

**Update**

This seems to  confirm my suspicion, that a copy/temp instance of the *evaluated expression* is passed, not the `ByRef` variable instance.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251769(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251769%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

> Placing the argument in its own set of parentheses forces evaluation of it as an expression...The result of the evaluation is placed in a temporary location, and a reference to the temporary location is received by the procedure. Thus, the original MyVar retains its value.

Comment: I think you mean End Sub.  Nice answer.

Comment: +1, here's my favorite discussion on this topic: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/

Comment: @DavidZemens Greate Answer.Big Help. Thanks