# What does this subtle VBA code change with brackets mean?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following code opens the default application for a filename:

```
Public Function OpenDefaultApplication(filename As String)
    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    sh.Open (filename)
    Set sh = Nothing
End Function
```

However, removing the brackets from the line opening the file means the file is not opened:

```
    sh.Open filename    ' does not work!
```

However, if I remove the code from a function, the code works successfully without brackets.

```
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
sh.Open filename ' works if not inside a function
Set sh = Nothing
```

What is this subtle different and why do the brackets become necessary inside a function?

Comment: Try `Ctrl+G`. Start typing ..

Comment: Why are you using a function for something with no return value?

Comment: On an unrelated note, [Shell.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is designed to open folders, [Shell.Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open files.

Comment: @MacroMan aren't sub / function interchangeable? If only visual basic was a real language...

Comment: @Andre451 the code doesn't work with shell.execute.

Comment: Please post your full code, including the definition of `filename`. How exactly are you calling `OpenDefaultApplication`? How do you run your second example? As A.S.H wrote, you can't run code outside of a function/sub.

Comment: @user3791372 A `Function` is used to return a value, a `Sub` is a sub-routine that doesn't return a value but may use functions within it. This is universal in programming - and FYI visual basic _is_ a real language, so is [tag:vb.net], [tag:vb6] and [tag:vba] (and your question is actually regarding VBA, not VB). There are many office programmers that could take that comment as a slur against their profession.

Comment: `Call sh.Open(filename)` fails, `Call sh.Open((filename))` succeeds, the difference is that in the latter example ByVal semantics are used in that the method receives a copy of filename.  This will likely by a COM oddity. What do you mean when you say *"remove the code from a function"*

Comment: @AlexK.Ahh, so it's just complaining that it wants a copy of the string, not the string itself? By "remove the code from a function", I meant run the code outside of a separate isolated function, e.g. an event handler

Comment: I meant `Shell.ShellExecute`, sorry. `sh.ShellExecute filename` works fine and is the correct method to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA What's the underlying difference between call Sub or Function with or without parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796803/vba-whats-the-underlying-difference-between-call-sub-or-function-with-or-withou)

Answer (score 2):

```
sh.Open filename
```

is actually the correct syntax.
Or alternatively

```
Call sh.Open(filename)
```

The original statement

```
sh.Open (filename)
```

**evaluates** `filename` and then passes it to `sh.Open`.
If you tried this syntax with a method that has two parameters:

```
sh.SomeMethod (filename, parameter2)
```

you'd get a syntax error.

So the question is:
What do you pass as `filename` to the first function, and what is `filename` in the second code example?

**EDIT**
For more clarification, add this to the beginning of `OpenDefaultApplication`:

```
Debug.Print filename
Debug.Print (filename)
```

and see the result in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was interesting.

You've hit a very odd behavior of the [Shell.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

```
Shell.Open(ByVal vDir As Variant) As Integer
```

Note that the parameter is defined as Variant, not String.
That's because you can also do e.g.

```
sh.Open 36
```

to open the Windows folder.

Apparently because of this, `sh.Open filename` doesn't work (though it's the correct syntax), since filename is passed as Reference.

`sh.Open (filename)` works, but is a rather ugly hack.

**Better solutions:**

1) Declare `filename` as Variant, if you insist on using Shell.Open:

```
Public Sub OpenDefaultApplication(filename As Variant)
    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    sh.Open filename
End Sub
```

2) Use the correct method to open files, [Shell.ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Public Sub OpenDefaultApplication(filename As String)
    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    sh.ShellExecute filename
End Sub
```